# There is no dialog box to input password for users other the main user

Tags: login, password, 15.10, users, accounts

I recently installed Ubuntu 15.10 (Ubuntu MATE) and created a main account, 'rwabuhesi' from which I created another one, 'qulay'.
From the terminal, I can log into both accounts and even move files between them, but on boot up, it only with the main account that I have a box into which I can enter a password.
When I select the other accounts including the guest account, I dont get this box, and therefore cant use them directly. I didnot have this problem while I ran Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
I am quite a newbie but familiar  with the basic commands.
I will appreciate any suggestions to solve my  Issue.

Answer (score 0):

I appeared that the account had slow keys active by default so that when I entered the password using onboard, everything worked.
The guest account worked when pressed an extra Enter key.